# IBM Websphere : Queue manager processing

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq, websphere-7

I have deployed my application on WebSphere and it is up and running and so are the queues associated with the application.

When I put messages on the queue I do not  see any processing in SystemOut.log file of the app server. This queue is supposed to process the message and then forward it to another queue.

Please tell me which log file to check the processing of the message being done my application.

Comment: I'm not aware of any WebSphere logs that record per-message processing but then I'm not a WAS guy.  I've added the [tag:websphere] tag to get better exposure for the question. WMQ won't log this activity unless it is transactional and then the transaction logs are not meant to be parsed for humans.  Typically, the app will write log entries on a per-message basis but where they go is up to the app.

Answer (score 1):

A really simple verification would be to inhibit the consumption of the messages.
Then your produced messages will stay in the queue.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the SIB or WebSphere MQ ?

As far as I know, the SIB does not log anything about message consumption by itself. However, you could use a logging framework such as Commons-Logging, Log4J, ... to add some logging details.